# Nested Sequential Model is not training

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build several models predicting different market developments, each using the same encoder network.
So I defined a shared LSTM Network like so:

```
def build_LSTM(layer_1_units=64, layer_2_units=128, dense_units_1=16, dropout=0.2, end_activation='softmax', optimizer='Adam'):
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      kl.LSTM(layer_1_units, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(SEQ_LEN, 56), name='Encoder/LSTM_1'),
      kl.LSTM(layer_2_units, name='Encoder/LSTM_2'),
      kl.BatchNormalization(name='Encoder/BatchNorm'),
      kl.Dropout(dropout, name='Encoder/Dropout'),
      kl.Dense(dense_units_1, activation='relu', name='Encoder/Dense')
  ])
  return model
```

I also defined a class for each market, which has the following model as a member:

```
class MarketModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, encoder_model, name):
    super(MarketModel, self).__init__()
    self.dense1 = kl.Dense(64, activation='relu', name=name + '/Dense_1')
    self.out = kl.Dense(2, activation='softmax', name=name + '/Out')
    self.encoder = encoder_model

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.encoder(inputs)
    x = self.dense1(x)
    return self.out(x)
```

So far so good, the models can all be trained on their respective data.
The LSTM model is built once and passed to each MarketModel as the `encoder_model`.
My goal is to have the LSTM learn to create a latent space which is then used by the additional Dense layers for prediction.
After checking the histograms, however, I realized that the encoder network weights are not changing at all.

I checked the `trainable_variables` and all layers are listed, so in theory this should work, right?
I also saved the encoder weights before a training step via

```
old_enc_weights = tf.identity(market.model.encoder.layers[4].weights[0])
```

and compared them to the weights after training

```
print(market.model.encoder.layers[4].weights[0] - old_enc_weights)
```

and sure enough, the weights did not change at all (the printed out result only contains 0's)

What am I missing? Shouldn't the gradient propagate through the Sequential LSTM network as well? Since I am only adding two layers, the gradient should not vanish, right?

Comment: Would you mind posting more complete code, it may be helpful in determining where things are going wrong.

Comment: Okay this is weird: I slapped together a quick Google Colab Notebook (to make sure the minimum working example actually works) and not only did the problem not occur there, but when I tried it again in my original notebook, the problem also vanished there. I tried looking through the older revisions to see if I changed anything, but did not find what fixed it :/ When looking into the histograms now, the encoder is actually training.
Must have been something stupid, I guess :/